# My code points that my list is out of range on line 9. Could someone tell me how to fix it?

Tags: python, list, range

```py
    v_leader=[]
        v_follower=[]
        distance=[]
        t_s=float(input("Enter the value of the time stamp"))
        r_t=float(input("Enter the vlaue of the reaction time"))
        i=t_s
        n=1
        while i<12.5:
            v_leader[n]=v_leader[n-1]+8*t_s
            i+=i
            n+=1
        m=n+1
        while m<n+11:
            v_leader[m]=v_leader[m-1]
        t=m+1
        while t<m+11:
            v_leader[t]=v_leader[t-1]-10*t_s
        print(v_leader)
```

I am trying to fix the `IndexError` raised by this line of code:

```py
v_leader[n]=v_leader[n-1]+8*t_s
```

Comment: If you want to add items to `v_leader` you need to do `list.append(x)`

Comment: Can you fix your code indentation?

Comment: What do you expect `v_leader[n-1]` to refer to during the very first time through the loop (when `v_leader` is completely empty)?

Answer (score 0):

All your lists are initiated as empty lists so in the looping process, your list will be `out of range`. You can use `try...except` to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access indexes greater than the length of the list. As all of your lists start out with 0 elements, calling `v_leader[n]` will always throws an error because there are no elements to access.
This can be fixed if, in the first loop, you ditch the counter n, and simply append new values.

```
while i<12.5:
    v_leader[n] += [v_leader[n-1]+8*t_s]
    i+=i
```

In your next loop, you can simply call something like `while m < len(v_leader) + 11:`.